# Channel Program object is not available in scratch org

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, standard-objects, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin

I'm creating a `Scratch Org`. Following is my command.

`sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias My-Scratch-Org --durationdays 30 --setdefaultusername --json`

But then once the org is launched, I cannot find the standard object `Channel Program`. This object is available in my `DevHub`.

Then I tried to deploy source to `My-Scratch-Org`. Then I got following error.

`Error: common\objects\ChannelProgram\ChannelProgram.object-meta.xml -> Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )`

Any help would be appreciated.

`{ API Version: 49.0, sfdx-version: sfdx-cli/7.69.0 }`

Comment: This is probably an issue with your scratch org definition file. A brief search tells me that this is a feature related to Communities. Does your definition file include "Communities" as a feature and set CommunitiesSettings > enableNetworksEnabled in the settings in your definition file?

Comment: @DerekF Yes, I have these settings in my scratch org definition file.

Comment: @DerekF when I change the edition to `Developer` from `Enterprise`, this issue is fixed, but now Language field of Case object is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Scratch Org Edition to `Developer` from `Enterprise` resolved the issue.

Comment: Note that Enterprise edition does not support user permissions in permissionsets whilst Developer edition does: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwWxAAK/issue-with-usersystem-permissions-in-permissionset-when-installed-via-unlocked-package